# How can I use a variable in root.findall('*/node[@color="keyword"]' of ElementTree XML API

Tags: xml, python-2.7, parsing, elementtree

I have the code:

```
var=red
CC1=root.findall('*/node[@color="keyword"]')
```

How can I use value of "var"(i.e exp) in 'keyword'? CC1 syntax was in ElementTree XML API